# C# Make Tree Node text downloadable link

Tags: c#, url, tree, ext.net

Here is the code I use to build the tree:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338439/8345061) from `Nick Saxelby`

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void NodeLoad(object sender, NodeLoadEventArgs e)
    {
        // NodeID stores the local disk path ( full path ) of the selected node to expand
        string path = e.NodeID;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NodeID))
        {
            foreach(var folder in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                string folderName = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folder).Name;
                Node folderNode = new Node();
                folderNode.Text = folderName;
                folderNode.NodeID = folder;
                e.Nodes.Add(folderNode);
            }

            foreach(var fileLeaf in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                Node treeNode = new Node();
                treeNode.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileLeaf);
                treeNode.NodeID = fileLeaf;
                treeNode.Leaf = true;
                e.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How I can make the `TreeNode` text a downloadable `url` so user can download the specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the link on a node, set `treeNode.Href` to the URL.

If the files are already hosted on your website alongside this page, I guess you know their URLs.

Say for example a local file like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Files\Directory\MyFile.txt` can be found at `http://example.com/Files/Directory/MyFile.txt`

In that case, you need to figure out that URL. I made a tool for "resituating" local file paths into web paths, it's a NuGet package called [PathMatcher](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VillageSoftware.PathMatcher/1.0.2.1) (scroll down in the docs to the 'PathMatcher.Resituate' section for examples)